# Java NIO implements pub/sub

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm learning Java NIO and what I want to do is to implement a pub/sub pattern clients and servers(My server maintain many long connections with clients). Here my question is my server how to select the specific channels to publish the message to subscriber(after server upload a message, it should only pub this messge to its subscriber, not everybody).

Also, I have some intuitive understandings about NIO, are they correct?

1. For each connection, in server side it is represented by a selectionkey.
2. If 1 is correct, is the selection key instance the same for each connection whenever the selector selects?

Comment: oh, I think I could use attach to assign the unique id for each selectionkey

Comment: 1. Use an appropriate data structure. 2. Yes. 3. The selection key is created when you register the channel with the selector, and doesn't change until you cancel it. Of course you could always cancel and re-register the channel, to get two successive keys, but why?